# Windows 10: how to get a list of ALL programs that are monitoring the keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-10, copy-paste, clipboard, cut-and-paste

***tl;dr: I need a program/script/code to give me a list of all currently running software on Win10 that monitors/affects the clipboard.***

---

I've had a super annoying issue on Windows 10 for at least a year now.  About 5%-10% of the time, my clipboard just doesn't work.

The issue occurs in 3 different forms (typically I only notice one at a time):

- Sometimes ctrl-c just doesn't work
- Sometimes ctrl-v just doesn't work
- Sometimes ctrl-x just doesn't work

For all forms of the issue, there is no feedback/error/noise or anything, it just silently fails.  Typically if I whack the shortcut key a bunch of times it eventually works.

I also get a warning in Excel that the clipboard isn't working, although funnily enough for Excel it generally DOES work, [it just annoys with me a modal with a false error.](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/18508126-remove-the-pointless-message-there-s-a-problem-wi)  But at least it's a hint that something is messing with the clipboard somehow.

I've tried isolation testing all the software ***that I can think of*** that does clipboard stuff... i.e. closing those program(s) for a while, but this hasn't got me anywhere.  **So I need to get a bit more organised in how I troubleshoot the issue, and the first step is to obtain a list of ALL software currently running that is monitoring/affecting the clipboard.  Is there any way to do this?**

Ideally a simple program or powershell script would be easiest.  But if I have to resort to writing some C# code, that's an option too.

Comment: Keys don't work the way you think. Each program that wants Ctrl+C has an accelerator has to register it. It only has effect if that program has the focus. So to your question NO there isn't. Programs that use the clipboard (in this example to copy) Opens the clipboard, preventing any other program from using it. Empties the clipboard becoming the clipboard owner, uses SetData to put each format onto the clipboard. Then closes the clipboard. Excel if different as it uses delayed rendering of clipboard formats. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-operations

Comment: Here is a clipboard diagnostic program in VB6. that I wrote many years ago. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvqkaKIXzvDigTDcA0910S2ZVxnq?e=JAryWZ It is only of use when the clipboard is not working. It will give you the PID of the program locking the clipboard.